# React doesn't rerender when using useRef with useImperativeHandle

Tags: reactjs

I have an editor `App` which consist of 3 elements: `MenuBar`, `EditorContent` and `div` for code view. `MenuBar` contains all the buttons which switches the view of the editor, including toggling between editor view (RichText) and code view (html), which is done by having

```
let [isCodeViewMode, setIsCodeViewMode] = useState(false);
useImperativeHandle(
    ref,
    () => ({
        getIsCodeViewMode: () => {
            return isCodeViewMode;
        },
    }),
    [isCodeViewMode]
);
```

and toggling this value by clicking a button. Inside my main App I'm trying to get the value of this state and adds `d-none` class to code view if it's false. Here is my code in `App`:

```
    let menuBarRef = useRef<any>();
    let isCodeViewMode = menuBarRef.current?.getIsCodeViewMode();
    console.log(isCodeViewMode);

return (
        <div
            id="editor-container"
            className="ps-relative s-textarea p0 d-flex fd-column"
            style={{ width: "1500px", zIndex: 10 }}
        >
            <div className="js-sticky py6 bg-inherit btr-sm w100 ps-sticky t0 l0 z-nav s-editor-shadow js-plugin-container js-sticky">
                <MenuBar editor={editor as Editor} ref={menuBarRef} />
            </div>
            <div
                id="editor-content"
                className="overflow-scroll fl-grow1 outline-none p12 pt6 w100 s-prose js-editor ProseMirror"
            >
                <EditorContent editor={editor} />
            </div>

            <div
                className={`mw-editor__codemirror ${isCodeViewMode ? "" : "d-none"}`}
            >
                <textarea></textarea>
            </div>
```

The problem is  while the value of `isCodeViewMode` is correctly updated inside `MenuBar` component, it's not being updated inside `App` component. What should I change to make it work?

Comment: Hi,  you won't see isCodeViewMode latest value unless App state changes. You will need to add a callback function to MenuBar to notify when isCodeViewMode had changed

Comment: I'm pretty new in React, how can I add this callback function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider

> When you change the ref.current property, React does not re-render
> your component. React is not aware of when you change it because a ref
> is a plain JavaScript object.

[caveats](https://react.dev/reference/react/useRef#caveats)

You need to add a function to `MenuBar` component to notify isCodeViewMode value has changed:

**MenuBar:**

```
useEffect(() => {
   onViewChanged(isCodeViewMode)
}, [isCodeViewMode])
```

**App:**

```
const [editorView, setEditorView] = useState(false);

...
 <div className="js-sticky py6 bg-inherit btr-sm w100 ps-sticky t0 l0 z-nav s-editor-shadow js-plugin-container js-sticky">
   <MenuBar editor={editor as Editor} ref={menuBarRef} onViewChanged={setEditorView} />
 </div>

...

 <div className={`mw-editor__codemirror ${editorView ? "" : "d-none"}`} >
    <textarea></textarea>
 </div>
```

Comment: it works but when  leave  `<div className={`mw-editor__codemirror ${isCodeViewMode? "" : "d-none"}`} >`
instead of ` <div className={`mw-editor__codemirror ${editorView ? "" : "d-none"}`} >
` since editorView is all the time undefined

Comment: Nice catch, I forgot to pass isCodeViewMode onViewChanged, I have updated the answer..it should be  onViewChanged(isCodeViewMode)

Comment: other solution is....Instead of calling onViewChanged(isCodeViewMode) in useeffect, you can call it directly after changing isCodeViewMode

Comment: Thank you! So in the end I don't need at all these useForwardRef, ref, useImperativeHooks etc right? I simply create a state inside `App` whose value is set using `useEffect` inside `MenuBar` and that all?

Comment: yes, in this case you don't need to use useImperativeHandle, you should only use it for imperative behaviors that you can’t express as props: for example, scrolling to a node, focusing a node, etc.